# Mapping pipes to multiple columns in tidyverse

Tags: r, mapping, tidyverse

I'm working with a table for which I need to count the number of rows satisfying some criterion and I ended up with basically multiple repetitions of the same pipe differing only in the variable name.

Say I want to know how many cars are better than Valiant in mtcars on each of the variables there. An example of the code with two variables is below:

```
library(tidyverse)

reference <- mtcars %>% 
     slice(6)

mpg <- mtcars  %>% 
  filter(mpg > reference$mpg) %>%
  count() %>% 
  pull()

cyl <- mtcars  %>% 
  filter(cyl > reference$cyl) %>%
  count() %>% 
  pull()

tibble(mpg, cyl)
```

Except, suppose I need to do it for like 100 variables so there must be a more optimal way to just repeat the process.

What would be the way to rewrite the code above in an optimal way (maybe, using `map()` or anything else that works with pipes nicely so that the result would be a tibble with the counts for all the variables in `mtcars`?

I feel the solution should be very easy but I'm stuck.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or:

```
library(tidyverse)

map_dfc(mtcars, ~sum(.x[6] < .x))

map2_dfc(mtcars, reference, ~sum(.y < .x))
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `summarise` + `across` to count observations greater than a certain value in each column.

```r
library(dplyr)

mtcars %>%
  summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. > .[6])))

#   mpg cyl disp hp drat wt qsec vs am gear carb
# 1  18  14   15 22   30 11    1  0 13   17   25
```

---

- `base` solution:

```r
# (1)
colSums(mtcars > mtcars[rep(6, nrow(mtcars)), ])

# (2)
colSums(sweep(as.matrix(mtcars), 2, mtcars[6, ], ">"))

# mpg  cyl disp   hp drat   wt qsec   vs   am gear carb
#  18   14   15   22   30   11    1    0   13   17   25
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it in a loop for example. Like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

reference <- mtcars %>% 
  slice(6)

# Empty list to save outcome
list_outcome <- list()

# Get the columnnames to loop over
loop_var <- colnames(reference)
for(i in loop_var){
  nr <- mtcars  %>% 
    filter(mtcars[, i] > reference[, i]) %>%
    count() %>% 
    pull()
  # Save every iteration in the loop as the ith element of the list
  list_outcome[[i]] <- data.frame(Variable = i, Value = nr)
}

# combine all the data frames in the list to one final data frame
df_result <- do.call(rbind, list_outcome)
```